# Total current current equation in P-N junction

Tags: voltage, current, pn-junction

[image]

[image]

So Okay I get why there is a negative sign in the equation for diffusion current of holes since the gradience is actually negative if we put our coordinate axis in the bottom left corner for example in the 2nd picture where x points right side..
But that then makes Jp overall positive, There is no negative term in the equation, How is that possible if you actually know that in a no bias situation the total current is equal to zero?

The same applies to Jn. The only possible way I could understand this is by substituting E with a negative sign since it points to the left in the 2nd picture.

Any clarifications ?

Comment: As I stated above I assumed x-direction is pointing right side. Since the density of P is decreasing as you go to the right side it means that the derivative is negative

Comment: First, Non bias state at equilibirum. Second, When is the gradient of P is positive if you take the coordinates axis bottom left corner of the picture for all values of positive x?  there isnt ?

Comment: I think you need to tell more about the conditions you are assuming. What biasing (forward, reverse, none)? Are you interested in the final equilibrium state or looking at some intermediate state?

Comment: I said "First, Non bias state at equilibirum."

Comment: What is Trump doing in ESE though :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure we are on the same page, all of these various \$J\$ terms are conventional current density. An electron moving right constitutes a \$J_n\$ to the left.

Now, lets get the signs of all these current components correct. My coordinate system is positive to the right.

\$J_{p(Drift)}\$ is a negative quantity. Holes drift left.

\$J_{p(Diff)}\$ is a positive quantity. Holes diffuse right.

\$J_{n(Drift)}\$ is a negative quantity. Electrons drift right.

\$J_{n(Diff)}\$ is positive quantity. Electrons diffuse left.

> The only possible way I could understand this is by substituting E with a negative sign since it points to the left in the 2nd picture.

Yes. the electric field is negative in the depletion region. This is how I arrived at my drift currents above.

---

> I get why there is a negative sign in the equation for diffusion current of holes since the gradient is actually negative

That is not why the negative sign is there. The negative sign is there since its a part of Fick's law of diffusion:

\$J=-D\nabla\psi\$

where \$D\$ is diffusivity and \$\psi\$ is concentration.

That is, things will diffuse in the opposite direction of the concentration gradient. Moving from high concentration to low concentration.

In the equation for \$J_{n(Diff)}\$ the sign is reversed. This is to account for the negative charge of electrons.

Comment: So basically I should just setup a cooridinate axis, And substitute E with a negative or a positive sign depending on its direction ? If that so this would make sense and thanks for clarifying why there is a negative sign.

Comment: @DonaldTrump I wouldn't substitute E with anything unless it was to plug in numbers to perform a calculation. Then E either is positive or negative depending on your device. In this case it is negative. Note that my listing of signs of each current component is specific to this device. If you flipped it around, or defined your axes different, all those signs would change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's all in terms of conventional current flow, even when it's electrons. That's what my book seems to say.
[image]
[image]

Modern Semiconductor Devices for Integrated Circuits - Chenming C. Hu

Comment: Does this help? I might be misinterpreting your question since it's been forever and I wasn't very good at it in the first place

Comment: I mean the book assumes two different axis so that both slopes are positive? Not really getting it. What I am suggesting is a slight change to the equations. In the 2nd picture I attached above and if you place the x axis pointing right and the E field points left it should be something like this

Comment: Jp = -Dp dp/dx - qpu_p E
Where I assumed current direction is right side. dp/dx is negative so it will contribute a positive diffusion current, Since E is pointing to the left it means drift current is in the opposite direction so a negative sign there, At least here you can see that they can reach equilibrium.

Comment: @DonaldTrump "Since E is pointing to the left". Why? Are we talking about reverse bias situation? Please be more explicit in context when speaking.

Comment: Edited the 2nd picture so it makes sense

Comment: @DonaldTrump I think I understand your question, but as I said, I'm not very good so take what I say with a grain of salt. Isn't it because drift currents always follow the electric field but diffusion currents always go from P to N for holes and N to P electrons? Which is then negated to convert to conventional current).

Comment: I agree and understand what you meant with diffusion current. But with drift current, Wouldnt the electric field make some minority free electrons on left (P junction) and push them to the right (n Junction)? And similarly to the minority Holes in the n Junction will push them to the left (P junction). This what I actually understood from the topic and I am just following the logic but the equations dont say so.

Comment: @DonaldTrump That makes sense but wouldn't those values just be rolled up into one of the other two values? It might also be because this is a first order approximation (I'm not sure, but it looks suspiciously simplistic, no?)

Comment: Not following, Could you please clarify?

Comment: @DonaldTrump I just feel like the model is too simple so suspect there are effects being neglected (just everything physical always seems way more complicated than this appears to be). With regards to the "rolling up", it could be that the minority carriers remaining behind influence the gradient and thus the diffusion, while those that cross over are accounted for in the drift. So there may not be a need to account for them independently. This is just conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

In bias condition, considering the figure that you posted holes will diffuse towards the right side since their concentration is lower in the depleted region. At the same time holes in the depleted region will move to the left side following the field. This means that we have fluxes in different direction.

Same thing applies for the electrons.
It's important to understand that field is only in depletion region and diffusion is at the boundary between depleted region and n/p doped region (Also the depleted region is doped of course)